# Create a scrolling slide in R presentation mode (.Rpres)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a slide that intentionally has an incredible amount of code output. I'd like to be able to scroll down just to give the viewers a quick idea of how much output there can be from simple code. Is there some way to instruct the output from a .Rpres file to scroll when it's rendered as HTML?

Below is sample code that can be used to make a slide with a lot of output:

````
Which Independent Variables Matter?
========================================================
```{r, echo=FALSE}
lm_all <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt, data = mtcars)
summary(lm_all)
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrolling of the window is disabled by default using CSS in R presentations.

You can override this by providing your own CSS rule. Add the following to the top of your .Rpres document:

```
<style>
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Alternatively you can create an external CSS document with the above rule included (do not include the  tags).

You reference this external CSS document in your .Rpres document as described in [this article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532307) under the section "Using Custom CSS".